# objective-zip Xcode 4.3 issue

Tags: objective-c, ios5, linker-errors, xcode4.3

I want to use objective-zip with an iOS 5 project under Xcode 4.3 but when I run my application in the simulator, this linker error appears to me:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZipFile", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AddMeetingViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230625/objective-zip-iphone-ios-5-issue) has the same problem as me, but his solution doesn't solve my problem.

Any help about this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And the Objective-Zip library is compiled for ARM6, ARM7 **and** i386?

Comment: Is the library compiled for the correct architecture?  You know that the iPhone is ARM but the iPhone Simulator is i386?

Comment: i don't know that but i didn't receive any compiler errors, i just receive this linkage error on running my app, also i have a working objective-zip demo which works well on the simulator

Comment: OK, that sounds OK then.  Can you show us the linker command line (available from within the Xcode Log Navigator).

Answer (score 1):

i have resolved my problem as following:

1) objective-zip source files must be included inside the compile
    sources section in build phases.

2) objective-zip doesn't use ARC so you must add these command
    `-fno-objc-arc` to all the source files mentioned in step 1 to tell
    the compiler not to use ARC with these files.

3) to add these command to the source files , hold the cmd button
    and select all the source files then press enter and type this
    command in the text box that appears.

Comment: dude, 1)  helped me a lot